# Retrieving data from Meteor server

Tags: react-native, meteor, react-native-meteor

I am trying a hello world app using `react-native, Meteor and xvonabur/ react-native-meteor`.
I am trying to subscribe to the data from MongoDB.

server code :

```
 import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
    import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';

    export const Pokemon = new  Mongo.Collection('pokemon');

    Meteor.publish('pokemon', () => {
        return Pokemon.find({});
    });
```

Client code:

```
export default createContainer(params=>{
    Meteor.subscribe('pokemon');

    return{
        pokemon: Meteor.collection('pokemon').find({})
    };
}, PokeMap);
```

As I understood after reading previous posts on stackoverflow, I have to define `export const Pokemon = new  Mongo.Collection('pokemon');` in a common scope to both server and the client. My client and the server are in Two different folders.

I tried to import `pokemon.js` in to the client as follow,

```
import { Pokemon } from '../../pokeserver/imports/collections/pokemon.js'
```

and tried to use it as follow;

```
export default createContainer(params=>{
    Meteor.subscribe('pokemon');

    return{
        pokemon: Pokemon.find({}),
    };
}, PokeMap);
```

But I am getting following error,

```
undefined Unable to resolve module `../../pokeserver/imports/collections/pokemon.js` from `Src\PokeMap.js`:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your import is wrong. You are doing an `export default`, which means that you don't need the brace around `Pokemon`

```
import Pokemon  from '/imports/collections/pokemon.js'
```

Should do the trick

Comment: I tried it, but still am getting the same error. Unable to resolve "../../pokeserver/imports/collections/pokemon.js" from "Src\PokeMap.js"

Comment: Just go do the meteor react tutorial and all will be clear.

Comment: Maybe you moved the file. An `Unable to resolve...` error is 99% due to typo in path or file has been moved.